# passing an observable array as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am developing an accounting software in ASP.Net MVC 5 and KnockoutJs.
I am new to KnockoutJs and Javascript, so have some difficulty.

I want to pass an observable array to a function which will calculate the account code for me. And in that function I want that array.

My Code:

```
self.SUBACCOUNTS = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedSubAccount.subscribe(function (newValue) {                           
    self.ACCOUNT_CODE = GenrateAccountCode(self.SUBACCOUNTS());
});
function GenrateAccountCode(accArray)
{
    //want to access some value of the passed array here
}
```

I want to assign the return value of the above function to a observable variable (`self.ACCOUNT_CODE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access some value of your observable array, you can use the `ko.utils.arrayForEach` function with the following sample usage:

```
// where accArray === self.SUBACCOUNTS()
function GenrateAccountCode(accArray)
{
     var initialCode = 0;
     //want to access some value of the passed array here
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(accArray, function(subaccount){
         // process the values of the array here. Assume each SUBACCOUNTS() item has a code property
          initialCode += subaccount.code();
     });
     return initialCode;
}
```

and then to set the your `self.ACCOUNT_CODE` observable to be the return value of the function, you could do this:

`self.ACCOUNT_CODE(GenerateAccountCode(self.SUBACCOUNTS())`